# Часто падает MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет! Такая проблема. Часто падает мускул. Последний раз этой ночью. Вот последние записи с лога:

```
170622  3:17:42 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.0.27-MariaDB-1~wheezy
key_buffer_size=4194304000
read_buffer_size=16777216
max_used_connections=171
max_threads=502
thread_count=32
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 275523273 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2b)[0x7f296691d96b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x433)[0x7f296649f583]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0a0)[0x7f2965ae70a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x922610)[0x7f2966838610]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x922da9)[0x7f2966838da9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x927894)[0x7f296683d894]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x929231)[0x7f296683f231]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50)[0x7f2965adeb50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f29641e895d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170622 03:17:45 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
170622 03:17:45 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
170622  3:17:46 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
170622  3:17:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.27-MariaDB-1~wheezy) starting as process 24410 ...
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
170622  3:17:47 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170622  3:17:48 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170622  3:17:48 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 141140685334
170622  3:17:48 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
170622  3:17:48 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
170622  3:17:48 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
170622  3:17:51 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
170622  3:17:51 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 141143459957
170622  3:17:55 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 25067981, file name /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.000427
170622  3:17:57 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table imas4/items_innodb in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 400, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
170622  3:17:57 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
170622  3:17:57 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
170622  3:17:57 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.31-77.0 started; log sequence number 141143459957
170622  3:17:57 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 10% 9% 19% 29% 39% 49% 59% 69% 79% 90% 100% (1.2 seconds); transactions to roll back: 2 1 0 (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 (4.7 seconds); 
170622  3:18:03 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: recovery done
170622  3:18:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170622  3:18:03 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
170622  3:18:04 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
170622  3:18:04 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
170622  3:18:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '10.0.2.15'.
170622  3:18:06 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
170622  3:18:06 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
170622  3:18:06 [ERROR] Aborting

170622  3:18:07 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
170622  3:18:07 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170622  3:18:13 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 141143508178
170622  3:18:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170622 03:18:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Вот конфиги MySQL:

```
   # MariaDB database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
#innodb_force_recovery = 4
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
bind-address           = 10.0.2.15
#
# * Fine Tuning
#

max_connections     = 500
max_user_connections    = 20
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 32M
thread_cache_size       = 256
#sort_buffer_size   = 32512M
sort_buffer_size        = 512M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 32M
#tmp_table_size     = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 64M

thread_concurrency = 12
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover          = BACKUP
#key_buffer_size        = 16096M
key_buffer_size = 4000M
#open-files-limit   = 200
#table_open_cache   = 2000
table_open_cache = 512
#myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32096M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096M
concurrent_insert   = 2
#read_buffer_size   = 64M
read_buffer_size        = 16M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 16M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 256K
#query_cache_size       = 256M
query_cache_size                = 64M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.

server-id  = 1
slave-compressed = 1
binlog-do-db = imas

#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
#max_binlog_size         = 200M
max_binlog_size         = 50M

# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 256M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size    = 4096M
innodb_log_file_size    = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 32M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_read_only=0
innodb_thread_concurrency = 12
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
#max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 64M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Оперативка 32 гига. Как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В логе ошибка что адрес занят. Может что-то запущено на порту 3306. Это нормально?

Comment: Vlad Vetrov, Это в результате попытки самому переподняться, а вопрос в том почему он упал. Именно ошибка 170622  3:17:42 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;

Comment: signal 11 = segmentation fault

Comment: sanmai, И что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Как пишут вам в ошибке...

```
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads 
   = 275523273 K  bytes of memory
```

С текущими настройками MySQL может использовать до 275 гигабайт памяти. Вы пишите что у вас на сервере её лишь 32 гигабайта.

`key_buffer_size` у вас 4 Гб - если вы не пользуетесь MyISAM, то стоило бы уменьшить значение в этой директиве. В остальном погоды она не делает.

Смотрим дальше. В сумме `read_buffer_size` и `sort_buffer_size` дают 528 Мб. У вас в моменте было 171 соединения, которые с такими показаниями как выше могли в моменте занять *90 гигабайт* памяти. Которой у вас нет.

Очевидно, сервер у вас нагруженный и уменьшать количество соединений нельзя. Значить нужно уменьшать размер буферов. На буферы максимум у нас есть 28 Гб за вычетом тех четырёх выше. Если исходить из максимум 256 соединений, то на одно соединение может приходиться не более порядка 100 мегабайт.

Значит с такими параметрами ваш сервер *хотя бы* не будет падать:

```
sort_buffer_size        = 100M
read_buffer_size        = 128K
max_connections         = 256
```

Будет ли он работать так быстро, как вы хотите - вопрос отдельный. Может быть стоит добавить индексы, может - добавить памяти в сервер. А может вам одного сервера так и так будет мало.